# What is idiomatic way to vendor non-go dependencies

Tags: go, govendor

What is the idiomatic way to vendor or otherwise include non-go dependencies?

I have a project which uses Postgres stored procedures for audit tracking. Those stored procedures are in a separate Git repo. In node projects, I would use `git submodule` to include it into my project. But in Go, vendoring is the standard. Go module and other vendoring tools are generally made for managing Go dependencies.

So, back to the original question, what is the idiomatic way to import general non-Go dependencies?

Comment: What prevents you from using one of [several, readily-available tools](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools) for Vendoring?

Comment: I can think of several ways of doing it, but I feel like I am working against the grain. Git submodule would work, go mod + godep would work... But this does not feel clean. I suppose I could use only godep, but should I even now that modules are in?

Comment: "Clean" is a bit too vague to formulate an answer against.  Can you provide a more precise metric?

Comment: Go is opinionated on just about everything. I was hoping there was an official opinion on vendoring non-Go dependencies. Clean simply means that I want to do what the rest of the community is doing and not invent my own way.

Comment: There is no "official opinion" on the topic that I've ever seen. Do whatever works best for your project. Personally, I wouldn't vendor them at all; vendoring is for importing Go libraries, and you're talking about non-Go code. If it's not involved in the compile phase, it's not a module, and shouldn't be treated as one. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Well, I consider my DB schema part of my app... Any way thanks. It is useful to know that I did not miss the "official opinion".